# How to solve this delay differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations, delay-differential-equations

How to solve this DDE:
\begin{align} \frac{1}{N_t} \frac{dN_t}{dt}=r\left(1-\frac{N_{t-\tau}}{K}\right) \end{align}
where $N_0,K,r,\tau$ are constant?

This differential equation is based on logistic model, which adds a delay $\tau$ to its equation, namely **delayed logistic model**.

Comment: This equation has infinitely many solutions (depending n an arbitrary function). You should specify further conditions to single out one of them. Specifying $N_0$ is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify, denote $y(t)=\log N_t$. Then we have a simple differential-difference equation
$$y'(t)=f(y(t-\tau)),\quad f(y)=r(1-y/K).$$
Let $\phi$ be an arbitrary continuous function on $[0,\tau]$
which has one sided derivative at $\tau$ satisfying $\phi'(\tau-)=\phi(0)$.
Then the formulas $Y(t)=\phi(t), 0\leq t\leq \tau$, and
$$y(t)=y(n\tau)+\int_{n\tau}^t f(y(t-\tau))dt, \quad n\tau\leq t\leq (n+1)\tau,\quad n\geq 1$$
defines a continuous solution which is everywhere continuous and continuously differentiable for $t\geq \tau$. Then $N_t=\exp(y(t))$ defines a solution of your problem.

Comment: You mean you define $y(t)=\phi(t)$ on $[0,\tau]$?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Yes, sure.

Comment: Then you need $\phi$ to be everywhere differentiable too, not just one-sidedly at $\tau$, right?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: On $[0,\tau]$ it is as good as $\phi$, but for $t>\tau$ its smoothness improves: if $\phi$ is only continuous, $f$ is continuously differentiable for $t>\tau$, twice continuously differentiable for $t>2\tau$ and so on.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks